# Number of partitions after wide-transform in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Does the number of partitions during and after a wide transform remain equal to the shuffle.partitions parameter or do they return to the original one after the wide transformation is complete? During a wide transform all shuffle partitions must be assigned a task ?

Comment: Explain your question.

Comment: During the wide transformation data are "split" into the shuffle partitions. My question was about what happens to these partitions after the transformation is complete. Do the number of partitions remains equal to shuffle partitions or do the partitions"group" back to their original number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once the wide transform is done the number of partitions returns to normal. Verified the same by setting the spark shuffle partitions and running a wide transformation and checking red.getNumPartitions. You can try that with simple spark job.